# Mail content doesn't break line

Tags: symfony, phpmailer

I send mail using PHP mailer in Symfony 2.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = MAIL_HOST;
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = MAIL_SMTP_DEBUG;
    $mail->Port       = MAIL_PORT;
    $this->setFrom($mail, $params);
    $this->setFromName($mail, $params);
    $this->setAddress($mail, $params);
    $this->setCc($mail, $params);
    $this->setBcc($mail, $params);
    $this->setWordWrap($mail, $params);
    $this->setIsHtml($mail, $params); // = false
    $this->setSubject($mail, $params);
    $this->setBody($mail, $params);
    $this->setAltBody($mail, $params);
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $r = $mail->Send();
```

Get mail content using file_get_content()

```
$body = file_get_contents($params["mailPath"] . "/registMailContent.html.php");
```

The plain text has neat content but the email has content in one line. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you displaying it on html page? I never used Symfony but maybe it's returning to already formated in that way text. Check that by putting that response inside <pre> block.

Comment: No, I send this email without using HTML format. It is well-formatted plain text with line breaks. The problem is the receving email is just one line. HTML = false so I can't use <pre>.

Comment: Have you tried to send email with adding `\n` to it?

Comment: Maybe you should show us a mail body? To break lines without html you should use `\n` symbol

Comment: Also why are you using phpmailer? Symfony2 has default Swiftmailer bundle and it's actually great.